# Dynamics CRM executing multiple requests c#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I want to update a field of an account and  I have the guid of account.

Can I update the field (for instance, address of the account) without retrieve request using an update request?

Here my code

```
Entity account= _service.Retrieve("account", Guid.Parse(accountGuid), new ColumnSet(true));
account.Attributes["new_password"] = password;
_service.Update(account);
```

Is it possible to use `ExecuteMultipleRequest` in this scenario?

Comment: have you tried anything ? then please post your code

Comment: Entity account= _service.Retrieve("account", Guid.Parse(accountGuid), new ColumnSet(true));
                account.Attributes["new_password"] = password;
                _service.Update(account);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Id of the record, yes, it can be done without a Retrieve.

Just write

```
Entity accountToUpdate = new Entity("account");
accountToUpdate.Id = Guid.Parse(accountGuid);
accountToUpdate["new_password"] = password;
_service.Update(accountToUpdate);
```

`ExecuteMultipleRequest` is used to batch multiple request at once, in that case you need to create first an `UpdateRequest` and add to the collection first, you can google for examples.